# how to get invoice values to google sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery().invoice({
    addRow: "#addRow",
    delete: ".delete",
    parentClass: ".item-row",

    no: ".no",
    price: ".price",
    qty: ".qty",
    total: ".total",
    totalQty: "#totalQty",

    subtotal: "#subtotal",
    discount: "#discount",
    shipping: "#shipping",
    grandTotal: "#grandTotal"
  });
});
(function(jQuery) {
  $.opt = {}; // jQuery Object

  jQuery.fn.invoice = function(options) {
    var ops = jQuery.extend({}, jQuery.fn.invoice.defaults, options);
    $.opt = ops;

    var inv = new Invoice();
    inv.init();

    jQuery('body').on('click', function(e) {
      var cur = e.target.id || e.target.className;

      if (cur == $.opt.addRow.substring(1))
        inv.newRow();

      if (cur == $.opt.delete.substring(1))
        inv.deleteRow(e.target);

      inv.init();
    });

    jQuery('body').on('keyup', function(e) {
      inv.init();
    });

    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

function Invoice() {
  self = this;
}

Invoice.prototype = {
  constructor: Invoice,

  init: function() {
    this.calcTotal();
    this.calcTotalQty();
    this.calcSubtotal();
    this.calcGrandTotal();
  },

  /**
   * Calculate total price of an item.
   *
   * @returns {number}
   */
  calcTotal: function() {

    jQuery($.opt.parentClass).each(function(i) {
      var row = jQuery(this);
      var total = row.find($.opt.price).val() * row.find($.opt.qty).val();

      total = self.roundNumber(total, 2);

      row.find($.opt.total).val(total);
    });

    return 1;
  },

  /***
   * Calculate total quantity of an order.
   *
   * @returns {number}
   */
  calcTotalQty: function() {
    var totalQty = 0;
    jQuery($.opt.qty).each(function(i) {
      var qty = jQuery(this).val();
      if (!isNaN(qty)) totalQty += Number(qty);
    });

    totalQty = self.roundNumber(totalQty, 2);

    jQuery($.opt.totalQty).val(totalQty);

    return 1;
  },

  /***
   * Calculate subtotal of an order.
   *
   * @returns {number}
   */
  calcSubtotal: function() {
    var subtotal = 0;
    jQuery($.opt.total).each(function(i) {
      var total = jQuery(this).val();
      if (!isNaN(total)) subtotal += Number(total);
    });

    subtotal = self.roundNumber(subtotal, 2);

    jQuery($.opt.subtotal).val(subtotal);

    return 1;
  },

  /**
   * Calculate grand total of an order.
   *
   * @returns {number}
   */
  calcGrandTotal: function() {
    var grandTotal = Number(jQuery($.opt.subtotal).val()) +
      Number(jQuery($.opt.shipping).val()) -
      Number(jQuery($.opt.discount).val());
    grandTotal = self.roundNumber(grandTotal, 2);

    jQuery($.opt.grandTotal).val(grandTotal);

    return 1;
  },

  /**
   * Add a row.
   *
   * @returns {number}
   */
  newRow: function() {
    jQuery(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-btn"><a class=' + $.opt.delete.substring(1) + ' href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a><input type="text" class="form-control no p-0 text-center" placeholder="No" type="text"></div></td><td class="item-name"><input type="text" class="form-control item p-0" placeholder="Item" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control qty p-0 text-center" placeholder="Qty" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control price p-0 text-center" placeholder="Price" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control total" type="text" readonly></td></tr>');

    if (jQuery($.opt.delete).length > 0) {
      jQuery($.opt.delete).show();
    }

    return 1;
  },

  /**
   * Delete a row.
   *
   * @param elem   current element
   * @returns {number}
   */
  deleteRow: function(elem) {
    jQuery(elem).parents($.opt.parentClass).remove();

    if (jQuery($.opt.delete).length < 2) {
      jQuery($.opt.delete).hide();
    }

    return 1;
  },

  /**
   * Round a number.
   * Using: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/number/round.html
   *
   * @param number
   * @param decimals
   * @returns {*}
   */
  roundNumber: function(number, decimals) {
    var newString; // The new rounded number
    decimals = Number(decimals);

    if (decimals < 1) {
      newString = (Math.round(number)).toString();
    } else {
      var numString = number.toString();

      if (numString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) { // If there is no decimal point
        numString += "."; // give it one at the end
      }

      var cutoff = numString.lastIndexOf(".") + decimals; // The point at which to truncate the number
      var d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff, cutoff + 1)); // The value of the last decimal place that we'll end up with
      var d2 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff + 1, cutoff + 2)); // The next decimal, after the last one we want

      if (d2 >= 5) { // Do we need to round up at all? If not, the string will just be truncated
        if (d1 == 9 && cutoff > 0) { // If the last digit is 9, find a new cutoff point
          while (cutoff > 0 && (d1 == 9 || isNaN(d1))) {
            if (d1 != ".") {
              cutoff -= 1;
              d1 = Number(numString.substring(cutoff, cutoff + 1));
            } else {
              cutoff -= 1;
            }
          }
        }

        d1 += 1;
      }

      if (d1 == 10) {
        numString = numString.substring(0, numString.lastIndexOf("."));
        var roundedNum = Number(numString) + 1;
        newString = roundedNum.toString() + '.';
      } else {
        newString = numString.substring(0, cutoff) + d1.toString();
      }
    }

    if (newString.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) { // Do this again, to the new string
      newString += ".";
    }

    var decs = (newString.substring(newString.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)).length;

    for (var i = 0; i < decimals - decs; i++)
      newString += "0";
    //var newNumber = Number(newString);// make it a number if you like

    return newString; // Output the result to the form field (change for your purposes)
  }
};
```

```css
.delete-btn {
  position: relative;
}

.delete {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: -1px;
  left: -16px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/js/metro.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4/css/metro-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table class="table compact table-border cell-border">

  <tr class="item-row">
    <th class="headNo">No</th>
    <th class="headItem">Item</th>
    <th class="headQty">Qty</th>
    <th class="headPrice">Price</th>
    <th class="headTotal">Amount</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody id="row">
    <tr id="hiderow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <a id="addRow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row" class="button">+</a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-right"><strong>Sub Total</strong></td>
      <td><input id="subtotal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Total Quantity: </strong><span id="totalQty">0</span> Units</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-right"><strong>Discount</strong></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" id="discount" value="0" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-right"><strong>Shipping</strong></td>
      <td><input class="form-control" id="shipping" value="0" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td class="text-center"><strong>Total</strong></td>
      <td><input id="grandTotal" class="form-control text-right" type="text" readonly></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="btn">Submin</button>
```

code of invoice in snippet
"No,Item,qty,Price,Amount" works prefect in client side and value of "No,Item,qty,Price,Amount" shown in console but i want to transfer "No,Item,qty,Price,Amount" values in google sheet. I tried using jquery but it only transfer one row data and repeat first row data in second row.How can i do that?

Comment: What are youu trying to do? Deploy a Google Apps Script WebApp? Or implement the Google Sheets API in Javascript?

Comment: Google Apps Script WebApp

Comment: In this case you need to implement server-side Apps Script functions and call those functions from client-side with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run). Show your Apps Script code you have so far.

Comment: I tried using following code:
**Client Side**
` $('#btn').click(function() {

  $('input[type="text"].item').each(function () {
var data = {};
    data.no= $(this).val();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().getInvoice(data);
});
**Server Side**
function getInvoice(data){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Sheet2");
ss.appendRow([data.no]);

}
Now i add two items in invoice, in sheet added two line but only first line's data appear.

Comment: The method `appendRow` can append only one row per call. What is the structure of `data` when you have two rows? Is is a 2D array? Can you log and show its structure?

Comment: Got the solution using javascript:
var data = {};
var no = document.getElementsByClassName("no");
data.noValues = no.length === 0 ? "" : Array.prototype.map.call(no,function(n){return n.value}).join(",");
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().getInvoiceNo(rowData);

@ziganotschka thank you